# Laravel Excel Package: Structuring Multiple level of data

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am trying to export my data to an excel sheet with [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) package. Everything is working fine. But I am struggling with the formation. Let's assume the data I am exporting is something like this:

```
$data = [{
 "id": 1,
"other_data": "other_data",
"meta_data": [
 {"id": 1, "info": "info"},
//similar objects
]
}];
```

I am using the `collection()` method in my **Export** class to return the exported data. Now I am also specifying the headings of Data. The problem is with the meta_data which needs to be structured just like the other data fields, right now all of it is stacked in one cell. I can do this using a loop but I don't think it is a good idea to loop each instance of data. Hence I think there might be some better way to do this.

Here's my Export class code:

```
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }


    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'ID',
            'Message',
            'Type',
            'Date',
            'User',
            'Meta_Data',
        ];
    }
```

What I expect is, the Meta_Data should be spanned to multiple sub rows of the original row and show it's contents rather than showing all the meta data in a column.

Like in this picture, each row will be like this:

[image]